# Adding row IDs to table in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to add a column with unique integers/hashes to a table to serve as the row id.

I created a table DUPLICATES with this query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE duplicates AS
SELECT
    "a", "b", COUNT(*) as _count
FROM
    "table"
GROUP BY
    "a", "b"
HAVING 
    _count > 1
ORDER BY 
 _count desc
```

Now I need to add a column that would contain unique ID for each row. I tried `ALTER TABLE DUPLICATES ADD 'id' int identity(1,1)`, however this returns: *SQL compilation error: Cannot add column 'id' with non-constant default to non-empty table 'DUPLICATES'*.

I am kind of short of ideas now as the discussions on Snowflake SQL are not widespread yet and the help page of Snowflake did not help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple method is to use `row_number()`:

```
CREATE TABLE duplicates AS
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as id,
           "a", "b", COUNT(*) as _count
    FROM "table"
    GROUP BY "a", "b"
    HAVING  _count > 1
    ORDER BY _count desc;
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this in Snowflake is to use Sequences. Pretty straight forward but they can be used to generate values for a primary key or any column that requires a unique value. How to use:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-sequences.html