# Set Column to iterate over set of numbers in SnowFlake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have spent days trying to solve this. I want a column in my snowflake table that iterates over a set of numbers. I can do this easily in Oracle SQL with this code:

```
alter table <table_name> add col_name numeric(10)
update <table_name> set col_name = mod(rownum,4)
```

the result is  
row 1 col_name = 1 
row 2 col_name = 2 
row 3 col_name = 3 
row 4 col_name = 4 
row 5 col_name = 1 
row 6 col_name = 2 
row 7 col_name = 3 
....

I know rownum doesnt exist for snowflake. I am aware of row_number() over (order by..) doesnt work in an update statement. I cannot use NORMAL or UNIFORM, or SEQ.
The closest I go was col_name = uniform(1, 4, random()) but this is random. I need it to be ordered. 
Cheers!

Comment: [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010378/adding-row-ids-to-table-in-snowflake-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the select statement you want, then replace the table, with the SELECT because that is 100% what the UPDATE is doing, and as a bonus you can order the how you want so the table has good performance.

```
CREATE OR REPLEACE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT
   a,
   b,
   c,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SEQ4()) % 4 AS col_name
FROM foo
ORDER BY your, clustering, keys
```

Comment: what does t1 and t2 represent?

Comment: stuff you might want to partition by, I was writing a generic look bit of SQL, verse I will drop it to look more how your case might want.

Comment: you would also want to use the COPY GRANTS and other life cycle values of the org table. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#syntax